# Access child class variable from base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, inheritance

```
class a : System.UI.Page {
int ab= c;
}
class b : a
{
public int c= 0;
}
```

I cant access it. I can access any control on the page by [Control.NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) Property in asp.net but **i have to access public variable from the class(i.e. class a) that is in form(i.e. class b)** so that i doesn't have write a particular method in 50 of my form.

Comment: Does class b inherit from System.Web.UI.Page?  Why not put the property on the base class since all inherited classes will have access to it?

Comment: Class a is inherited from System.Web.UI.Page.

Comment: for my kind reference can u post the full classes with getters n setters and all that cool stuff

Comment: @Aaron Hawkins. Seems a good solution, I will take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I will write it as an answer for you.

Comment: well access it using the Page property, why do u need the namingcontainer. i mean this.ab shud work rite since a is a Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the variable on the base class so that the inherited classes will have access to it.  For example:

```
class a : System.UI.Page
{
    protected int c = 0;
}

class b : a
{
    protected void DoSomething()
    {
        c = 1; //Access c from derived class.
    }
}
```

Also, if this property is not instance specific, you can always use a static property in the Global.asax file that can be accessed from anywhere within your ASP.NET application.  If it is session specific, you can simply have the property access the session and store/retrieve the value from there so that each user session has their own value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using inheritance in the wrong way. Try this, it should work:

```
public class a : b {
    int ab = c;
}

public class b : System.UI.Page
{
    public int c = 0;
}
```